# How to make HLS start from the begining

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I need some help with HLS streaming, I'm trying to create a playlist for streaming,

I'm using ffmpeg to generate the files and the .m3u8 files. And for playing i'm using a web page with videojs player

The idea is to simulate a live streaming using files already created.

The problem is that in some version of iphone works and in another does not work.
The problem is that when I start play the video in the Safari browser of my phone it freezes for a while and then download and play the last segment.

for example if the video is split in 4 differents .ts files.
It starts playing from the 4th .ts file and then stop.

The problem is that I have 2 iphone mobile phone, one of them works perfectly but the other one not

The not working cell phone is a iphone 6 (version 9.2.1)

Here is my m3u8 file. Note that I'm using the #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT and I remove the #EXT-X-ENDLIST from the botton. So it should be played as an live streaming.

It works for another phones, it begins from the 0 second when I set the #EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET=0

but in this version (9.2.1) the video freezes and then jumps to the last segment (webinar-3.ts) plays that segment and finally stop.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET=0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXTINF:5.046444,
webinar-0.ts
#EXTINF:5,
webinar-1.ts
#EXTINF:5,
webinar-2.ts
#EXTINF:5,
webinar-3.ts
```

Have anybody got an idea of what i'm doing wrong or how to get a m3u8 config that works for this iphone version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [section 6.3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-19#section-6.3.3) of the HLS specification:

> If the EXT-X-ENDLIST tag is not
> present and the client intends to play the media normally, the client
> SHOULD NOT choose a segment which starts less than three target
> durations from the end of the Playlist file.

In your case, this means the player will start playing from `webinar-3.ts`. As there are no more segments in the playlist, the video will then stop. In other words, the behaviour you are seeing is correct.

The EXT-X-START tag, which allows you to [specify the starting point of a video](http://hlsbook.net/how-to-start-playing-a-video-at-a-specific-point-in-time/), was introduced in version 6 of the protocol (not version 4) so you should change the value of the EXT-X-VERSION tag in your playlist accordingly.

If you want to start playback from the beginning of the video (and the event isn't live) why not just create a VOD playlist? Add all the segments to the playlist, remove the EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE tag (or set it to VOD), then add the EXT-X-ENDLIST tag to the end of the playlist.

Comment: Hi @Simon thanks for your answer, yeah i made a mistake in the example but i'm using #EXT-X-VERSION:6.

Comment: i have made a mistake in the example but I'm using #EXT-X-VERSION:6. The reason why I am not using the VOD event is because I want to simulate that the video is a Live streaming, so for example if somebody watch the video that person must not be able to rewind or forward the video as you can do with a VOD. Am I clear of what i want to achive?

That's why i am using an EVENT playlist type and removing the ENDLIST from the end of the playlist.

Now I have read HLS spec and yes the behaviour is like you said. in 9.2.1 version. Is there any workaround that could help me to do what i want?

Comment: The EVENT playlist type allows users to seek anywhere in the stream from the start of the event - segments are appended to the playlist, they are not removed from it. If you can control the video player, you could create a VOD playlist and disable the player controls. E.g. remove the rewind and fast forward buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This question had been posted long time ago, but I post my workaround to solve this for ones who have same trouble now and for my personal note.

In my case, the trick was setting duration to a very big value, like 99999999999.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET=0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:99999999999
#EXTINF:4.159091,
v000.ts
#EXTINF:4.090909,
v001.ts

...
```

As Simon mentioned, by default, the player does not start at the segment 0 but "safe live point," ~3 target durations from the end of the playlist. The idea of the workaround is setting "~3 target durations" to a ridiculous value and let the player handle this exception. It looks like the exception handling for this is starting at the beginning of the segments.

I hope this may help.